# How to create a two columns data frame from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I've a python dictionary

```
dict = {'Name':value,'Name2':value2,'Name3':value3}
```

And I want to create a DataFrame from there, but if I try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

I have two problems, first one is the not all items in the dictionary has the same value, second one and more important one, I want a one two column data frame in this format:

> Name1  value
> Name1  value
> Name1  value
> Name2  value
> Name2  value
> Name3  value
> Name3  value
> Name3  value
> Name3  value

Rather than:

> Name1   [value,value,value]
>
> Name2   [value,value]
>
> Name3   [value,value,value]

Comment: What is the expected output here? Are you after `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)`? Also don't name your dict variable `dict` this shadows the `dict` type

Answer (score 14):

```
value = 1
value2 = 2
value3 = 3

mydict = {'Name':value,'Name2':value2,'Name3':value3}
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict.items(), columns=['Name', 'Values'])
```

Gives

```
    Name    Values
0  Name2       2
1   Name       1
2  Name3       3
```

**Edited for giving support to lists in dictionary values:**

If `value`, `value2`and `value3` are lists:

```
import pandas as pd

value = [1,2,3]
value2 = [4,5,6]
value3 = [7,8,9]

mydict = {"Name1" : value, "Name2" : value2, "Name3" : value3 }
```

`mydict`is `{'Name1': [1, 2, 3], 'Name2': [4, 5, 6], 'Name3': [7, 8, 9]}`

Then, assign a key to every single value in the dictionary:

```
mylist = [(key, x) for key,val in mydict.iteritems() for x in val]
```

Now, we have `mylist` is

```
[('Name2', 4),
 ('Name2', 5),
 ('Name2', 6),
 ('Name3', 7),
 ('Name3', 8),
 ('Name3', 9),
 ('Name1', 1),
 ('Name1', 2),
 ('Name1', 3)]
```

And, finally, convert to dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(mylist, columns=['Name', 'Values'])
```

The result is

```
df= 

    Name  Values
0  Name2       4
1  Name2       5
2  Name2       6
3  Name3       7
4  Name3       8
5  Name3       9
6  Name1       1
7  Name1       2
8  Name1       3
```

Comment: Is it possible to have as much rows as values?

Comment: If in python 3, use `dict.items()` instead of `dict.iteritems()`. I.e. `mylist = [(key, x) for key,val in mydict.items() for x in val]`

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
dict1 = {'Name':1,'Name2':2,'Name3':3}
df = pd.DataFrame([[key,value] for key,value in dict1.iteritems()],
     columns=["Name","Value"])
```

Comment: Is it possible to have as much rows as values?

Comment: You mean to say that the dictionary has many key-value pairs in it?

Comment: Yes, but isn't necessary in the dict just in the Data Frame

Comment: change the iteritems to items